# Entry state showing different values when read directly and when read from a variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I am using entity framework 4.1 and code first in asp.net mvc.  Just to test learn i wrote below code (A controller).

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (var db = new DemoDataBase1Context())
            {
                //get person from db
                var person = db.Persons.FirstOrDefault();

                //get entry
                var entry = db.Entry(person);

                //now change the person object
                person.Name = "Some New Value";  

               //print entity state

                //this is showing unchanged
                sb.Append("<br>State: " + entry.State);  

                //this is showing changed
                sb.Append("<br>State: " + db.Entry(person).State);                 
            }

     return Content(sb.ToString());
}
```

In above code you can see, when iam doing `entry.State` its saying unchanged, if i do  `db.Entry(person).State` its saying changed. Can any one explain why??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have auto change detection enabled (which is the default in EF 4.1) `Entry` calls `DetectChanges` internally. The method starts probably similar to this:

```
if (Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled)
    ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
//...
```

In your second call of `db.Entry(person)` the object has changed and the `DetectChanges` method detects this by comparing a snapshot which was made when you loaded the entity with the current values. Since there is a difference the state changes from `Unchanged` to `Modified`.

Also the `State` of the `entry` object you have created before the change will go to `Modified` because `DbEntityEntry.State` is likely a property which just propagates the `State` value of the inner `_internalEntityEntry` which remains the same instance in both `DbEntityEntry` objects.

If you really want to save the former state of an entity you need to save the `State` itself, not only the `entry` object:

```
var state = db.Entry(person).State;
```

This is just an enum and won't change with a later call to `Entry`.

You can compare this behaviour with the behaviour when you disable automatic change detection:

```
db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
```

Both `sb.Append...` lines will receive the state `Unchanged` in that case because EF doesn't notice now anymore that one of your POCO properties has changed because `DetectChanges` isn't called.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Entry method gives you the state of the object as it is when you call Entry. I don't think it has anything to do with reading it from a variable versus calling it directly.

When you get your reference to the first entry, your object isn't changed. The very next line you change it and call Entry again, at which point it is changed. If you store a reference to that then compare the two I am guessing they are different references:

```
var person = db.Persons.FirstOrDefault();

// get reference to entry - unchanged at this point
var entry1 = db.Entry(person);

// make a change to the object
person.Name = "Changed";

// get reference to entry - changed now
var entry2 = db.Entry(person);

// these will not be equal: probably false
var equalOrNot = entry1 == entry2;
```

Comment: i just checked: after this statement `var entry2 = db.Entry(person);` | `entry1.State` and `entry2.State`, now both are saying Modified. Now i just commented out `var entry2 = db.Entry(person);`, `entry1.State`  shows Modified. I dont know why its happening.

Comment: Update your code to show what you are doing. When I ran my test it worked as expected.